# centos7 can't login through the x but work for ssh

Tags: centos

I have installed centos minimal version. I have disabled the nouveau and installed Nvidia driver before this issue.
When I reboot the system, only one bar flash there.

[image: Here is a picture]

Update the error show red in the journal is `Dependency failed for Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon`.

```
Starting MD Metadata Monitor on /dev/md127...
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Dependency failed for      Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Job spice-vdagentd.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/mapper/centos-swap.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MD Metadata Monitor on /dev/md127.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LVM2 PV scan on device 259:3...
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Job spice-vdagentd.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/centos-home.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounting /home...
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started LVM2 PV scan on device 259:3.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MD Metadata Monitor on /dev/md125...
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MD Metadata   Monitor on /dev/md125.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon.
Nov 08 19:48:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Job spice-vdagentd.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be a mistake in blacklist.conf, try using:

```
blacklist nouveau
```

Login through ssh (or another tty) and edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf with a console editor of your choice, for example, emacs or vim.